# Force equation number to be right aligned

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

I'm trying to typeset some basic equations with proper numbering. I simply want a single equation to have a right aligned number in the two column environment that I'm using. I tried three approaches, but none was satisfactory. I tried the regular `equation` environment, which produced a number on the next line; the `\mbox` approach which put the number directly next to the equation (could modify with some `\;` padding); and the `align` environment which produced no number. Specifically, I have the following

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{NPV}

\textit{NPV}_{System} = P_d+&P_{a}Y\left(\frac{1}{1+r},N\right)+C_cf_{OM}Y\left(\frac{1+i}{1+r},L\right)

\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{NPV}

\mbox{\textit{NPV}_{System} = P_d+&P_{a}Y\left(\frac{1}{1+r},N\right)+C_cf_{OM}Y\left(\frac{1+i}{1+r},L\right)}

\end{equation}

\begin{align} \label{NPV}

\mbox{\textit{NPV}_{System} = P_d+&P_{a}Y\left(\frac{1}{1+r},N\right)+C_cf_{OM}Y\left(\frac{1+i}{1+r},L\right)}

\end{align}

\end{document}
```

A few questions.

1. How does LaTeX determine the spacing and when to break the line (first example)?
2. Is there a way to use `\mbox` to right align and not just "keep together".
3. Why does `\align` not produce an equation number in this instance?

Some background: I'm using TeXnicCenter with LuaLaTeX though I get similar results using XeLaTeX.

Comment: If you get errors then the pdf output should only be taken as a general debugging aid, there is no point on commenting on the alignment. Tex isn't trying to align anything just recovering from errors. You are using math constructs not in math mode and get multiple errors `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $`

Comment: (There are 35 separate TeX errors reported on that MWE before it produces a pdf file)

Comment: not really relevant to the question, but there shouldn't be any blank lines between the `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` and similarly for `align`.  also, the `&` in the `equation`s isn't valid -- this example won't produce output, only an error log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix all errors before looking at the alignment, TeX's error recovery is designed to let it continue, not to make any reasonable output at the point of the error.

Your expression is just too long to fit on one line in 2 column, here are a couple of possibilities:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline} \label{NPV}
\mathit{NPV}_{\mathrm{System}} ={}\\
 P_d+P_{a}Y(\frac{1}{1+r},N)+C_cf_{\mathrm{OM}}Y(\frac{1+i}{1+r},L)
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}\label{NPV2}
\begin{gathered} 
\mathit{NPV}_{\mathrm{System}} ={}\\
 P_d+P_{a}Y(\frac{1}{1+r},N)+C_cf_{\mathrm{OM}}Y(\frac{1+i}{1+r},L)
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. The solution that you provided is adequate, but not optimal. I guess I don't understand why I get 35 errors - do I need to include $ or $$ in equation mode, as indicated in the error log? I'm writing a larger document that appears to handle other equations properly. Why not this one? Thanks!

Comment: hard to enumerate all the things wrong in the original:-) You can not use `&` in `equation` only in alignments, you can't have blank lines in equation, `\mbox` takes you out of math mode, so all math constructs such as `_` or `\left` inside the `\mbox` are in error, and so it goes...

Comment: @EricMorgan forgot to ping you on last comment:-)

Comment: Many thanks. Upon removal of the blank lines and ampersands the total number of errors was significantly reduced and the NPV equation in question now looks correct!